# Setting a variable to an operator then executing it

Tags: php, function, class, operations

I'm new to PHP in general. I was messing with this code until I wanted to execute the function in one set instead of having to set and add, sub, div, mult function. How do I go about setting the variable operator with the two num sets?

Example pseudo code:

```
<?php
$Num1 = 10;
$Num2 = 5;
$operation = /;
$Sum = $Num1 $operation $Num2;
return $Sum;
```

Or something like:

```
<?php
// creating Class "Math"
class math {
    //Executing the function
    function exec($info = array()) {
      return $info['num1'] $info['operation'] $info['num2'];
    }
}

// Set info
$info = array(
    'num1' => 10,
    'num2' => 5,
    'operation' => '/'
);

//execute the OOP
$math = new math;
echo $math->exec($info);
```

Comment: You can't... Use switch or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is referred to as the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

One way to do this is to define your functions

```
$multiply = function($operand0, $operand1) {
    return $operand0*$operand1;
};

$add = function($operand0, $operand1) {
    return $operand0+$operand1;
};
```

Then using your sample code:

```
class math {
    //Executing the function
    function exec($info = array()) {
      return $info['operation']($info['num1'], $info['num2']);
    }
}

// Set info
$info = array(
    'num1' => 10,
    'num2' => 5,
    'operation' => $add
);

//execute the OOP
$math = new math;
echo $math->exec($info); //will print 15
```

Comment: `return $operand0*operand1;` and `return $operand0+operand1;` will get a syntax error.